# Cambiar la versión de una biblioteca en google colaboratory

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colab

Para reproducir [la respuesta de CrazyElf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1254476/284043) (para ser capaz utilisar letras rusas en las columnas de la dataframe que utilisa lightgbm) necesito utilisar la version 2.2.3 y deshacerme de la version actual:

```
>>> import lightgbm
>>> print(lightgbm.__version__)
3.1.1
```

Entonces intento deshacerme con este versiones:

```
!pip uninstall lightgbm -y
!pip install lightgbm==2.2.3
```

Pero es muy extrano porque aqui piense que la version sea 2.2.3

```
Found existing installation: lightgbm 2.2.3
Uninstalling lightgbm-2.2.3:
  Successfully uninstalled lightgbm-2.2.3
Collecting lightgbm==2.2.3
  Using cached lightgbm-2.2.3-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from lightgbm==2.2.3) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from lightgbm==2.2.3) (0.23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from lightgbm==2.2.3) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn->lightgbm==2.2.3) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn->lightgbm==2.2.3) (1.0.0)
Installing collected packages: lightgbm
Successfully installed lightgbm-2.2.3
```

Y despues cuando importo la libreria todavia tengo la version 3.3.1

Comment: Intenta instalarlo usando `--no-cache-dir`, por ejemplo, `pip install --no-cache-dir lightgbm==2.2.3`. En su defecto proba borrando el cache `pip cache dir`. ¿Que versión de `pip` estas usando?

Comment: ¿Pudiste solucionarlo? Dependiendo de la versión de `pip` hay comando para limpiar el `cache`.